# symfony2 functional test email data collector messageCount 0 but email sent

Tags: symfony, phpunit, profiler, swiftmailer

I'm trying to implement a functional test for a registration form. Everything works so far, even the registration mail gets sent to a test email account. But I would like to check in my code, whether the mail gets sent or not.

This is what I have so far (the class extends WebTestCase and I'm using Symfony2.3 and phpunit 3.7.21):

```
$client = $this->client;
$client->followRedirects(true);
$client->enableProfiler();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/register');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Register')->form();
// In here I set some form data
$client->submit($form);
$mailCollector = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');
$this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());
$collectedMessages = $mailCollector->getMessages();
$message = $collectedMessages[0];
```

But I always get an `Failed asserting that 0 matches expected 1.` for the line `$this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());`.

Again, swiftmailer works and by running the test, I'm getting the expected mail. Just the Profiler seems to ignore it.

Here is what I get by `var_dump($mailCollector);`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't there a redirect after form submission? What if you set `followRedirects` to `false`?

Comment: Yes, there is. Setting followRedirects to false actually solved the problem. Thank you for the help. If you would like to post this as answer, I'd mark it correct. If you know why setting followRedirect to false works, I'd appreciate if you would add the explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `$client->followRedirects(false);`.

On background there might be a redirect after processing POST request and sending email. It's a common practice to prevent duplicate form submissions (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). And test client is automatically following this redirect doing another request.

If so, you are actually trying to get mail collector on a subsequent request which sends no mail.